# In PostgreSQL, how to generate clean JSON without the backslashes and outer double quotes?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

This PostgreSQL code:

```
do
$j$
declare arr text[];

begin

arr = array_append(arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'acg', 'v', 'val')::text);
arr = array_append(arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'xyz', 'v', 'xxx')::text);

raise info '%', (array_to_json(arr));
end;
$j$
```

Generates this:

```
["{\"k\": \"acg\", \"v\": \"val\"}","{\"k\": \"xyz\", \"v\": \"xxx\"}"]
```

I know I can run `regexp_replace` and clean it up, but isn't there a way to generate clean JSON?

Like this?:

```
[{"k": "acg", "v": "val"},{"k": "xyz", "v": "xxx"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you didn't intend to use `text` here, but want `jsonb`.

The code then would look as follows:

```
DO                                                                          
$j$                                                                         
DECLARE                                                                     
   arr jsonb[];                                                             
BEGIN                                                                       
   arr = array_append(arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'acg', 'v', 'val'));     
   arr = array_append(arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'xyz', 'v', 'xxx'));     

   RAISE NOTICE '%', to_jsonb(arr);                                         
END;                                                                        
$j$;
```

Te result is:

```
NOTICE:  [{"k": "acg", "v": "val"}, {"k": "xyz", "v": "xxx"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra characters you see are *not part of the value*, only of the display representation.

> Generates this:
>
> ```
> ["{\"k\": \"acg\", \"v\": \"val\"}","{\"k\": \"xyz\", \"v\": \"xxx\"}"]
> ```

That is (the output representation of) an array with two items; each item is a JSON string. That's what your code requested:

> ```
> arr = array_append(arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'acg', 'v', 'val')::text);
> arr = array_append(arr, jsonb_build_object('k', 'xyz', 'v', 'xxx')::text);
> ```

If you are going to use the JSON, you definitely want it as the text string you're getting.

The *representation* of that string will, of course, need to have special characters escaped to be clear which characters are part of the string, and which are not.

A text string value whose value is `{"k": "acg", "v": "val"}` will be *represented for display* with some of those characters escaped with backslashes, `"{\"k\": \"acg\", \"v\": \"val\"}"`. The backslashes and surrounding quotes and other extra characters are not part of the value.

So you need to choose between *rendering* the value for display as a PostgreSQL literal value, which requires escaping its special characters for output; or *using* the text string elsewhere (pass the value to another function, for example) as an actual value.

Comment: The reason I need a clean string is that I'm passing this to somewhere else that does not like the extra baggage, and I'd rather not do the cleanup.

Comment: @Kenobi, when you pass the result to its destination, what is the result? I attempted to explain that the value *is* a JSON string, without need of cleanup. The extra characters you see are *not part of the value*, only the display representation.